# Paste contents of a file to another file from a particular line

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I want to copy content of a text file (*description.txt*) and paste it on another text file at a particular line (*movie.txt*) using c++.

Here's the file contents:

***description.txt***

> Chris Gardner takes up an unpaid internship in a brokerage firm after he loses his life's earnings selling a product he invested in. His wife leaves him and he is left with the custody of his son.

***movie.txt***

> Movie name: The Pursuit of Happyness
> Movie Description:
> // description.txt content here
> Initial release: November 2006
> Director: Gabriele Muccino
> Adapted from: The Pursuit of Happyness

Answer (score 0):

I make a function that you can use.

```
void CopyContentOfTextFile(char* sourceFile, char* targetFile, int targetLine)
{

    FILE* resultFilePtr = fopen("result.txt", "w");

    FILE* sourceFilePtr = fopen(sourceFile, "r");
    FILE* targetFilePtr = fopen(targetFile, "r");


    char line[256];
    int lineCounter= 0;

    while (fgets(line, 256, targetFilePtr)!=NULL)
    {
        if (lineCounter == targetLine-1) 
        {
            char lineToBeAdded[256];
            //Now read sourceFile
            while (fgets(lineToBeAdded, 256, sourceFilePtr) != NULL)
            {
                fprintf(resultFilePtr, "%s", lineToBeAdded);
            }
            fprintf(resultFilePtr, "%s", "\n");
        }
        fprintf(resultFilePtr, "%s", line);
        lineCounter++;
    }

    fclose(sourceFilePtr);
    fclose(targetFilePtr);
    fclose(resultFilePtr);

    //Remove old movie.txt file with new one
    remove(targetFile);
    rename("result.txt", targetFile);

}
```

To call it use something like:

```
int main()
{
    char pathToSourceFile[] = "description.txt";
    char pathToTargetFile[] = "movie.txt";
    int line = 3;
    CopyContentOfTextFile(pathToSourceFile, pathToTargetFile, line);
}
```